# Storing title in localStorage is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

How can I store title in `localStorage`?

For example:

```
if (document.querySelector('li.selection').title != " ") {
      localStorage.setItem('test', document.querySelector('li.selection').title);
}
```

I'm receiving `"undefined"` for this the `value` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like below

```
<p><abbr id="myAbbr" title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">receive</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myAbbr").title;
    window.localStorage.setItem('test', x);
}
function myFunction1() {
    var x = window.localStorage.getItem('test');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

}
</script>
```

[W3schools snippet](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCDPZHX93UBB)

Also check that if you want to compare a empty string then you need not give `space` between quotes. And that could also be the reason for you getting undefined since the value may be undefined and not `space` and the condition would have passed.

```
if (document.querySelector('li.selection').title != "") {
      localStorage.setItem('test', document.querySelector('li.selection').title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have in the condition `title != " "` which is something like `if title does not equal **one space**` ... is means that if the title is not one blank character, then is the condition always true and than it could be for example undefined.

Have you tried replacing the space with an empty string (`""`) or `undefined`?

I would recommend you to use `element.getAttribute("title")` function which is better than directly accessing the title attribute.